# Group by values from 4 a.m to 4 a.m SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by, grouping

I have data from 04/01/2012 00:00 to 05/01/2012 05:00

let say

```
StartDate              Value 
04/01/2012 00:00       10 
04/01/2012 05:00       10 
04/01/2012 08:00       10

05/01/2012 01:00       10
05/01/2012 04:00       10
05/01/2012 05:00       10
```

if I do a group by date

```
SUM(Value)...
GROUP BY YEAR(StartDate), MONTH(StartDate),DAY(StartDate)
```

this group data from 04/01/2012 00:00 to 05/01/2012 00:00 and sum the full day value i.e 30

but I need to group by different time

i.e 04/01/2012 04:00 to 05/01/2012 04:00 so that the result will be 40

how to achieve this. Anyone did this before...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SUM(Value)
...
GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD(hour, -4, MyDateCol) AS Date)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select dateadd(hh, 4, date) as date, total from (
    select
        dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, dateadd(hh, -4, startDate)), 0) as date, 
        sum(value) as total
    from yourTable 
    group by dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, dateadd(hh, -4, startDate)), 0)
) t
```

Result:

```
date                    total
2012-01-03 04:00:00.000 10
2012-01-04 04:00:00.000 30
2012-01-05 04:00:00.000 20
```